# How do I change the default database owner for new databases in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, logins, owner

I had cause to change my computer name (it’s running in a virtual machine). I have an existing SQLExpress instance which was installed prior to the rename.

There are some features which fail because new databases are still created with the old owner. More specifically, when I try to create a new database diagram, I get the below error.

> Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'OLDNAME\user', error code 0x534. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15404).

I used the following instructions to rename the server:

```sql
sp_dropserver 'OLDNAME\SQLEXPRESS';
GO
sp_addserver 'NEWNAME\SQLEXPRESS','local';
GO
--  Restart Server
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;    --  NEWNAME\SQLEXPRESS
```

However, this did not affect the default owner for new databases. They are still being created with the owner as `OLDNAME\user`, who no longer exists.

I know how to change the owner of an existing database, after creation. But, how can I get new databases to have the correct owner to begin with?

Comment: What features are failing, and what are the error messages?

Comment: There’s only one, an I admit it’s not too important: When I try to create a new database diagram, I get the message: `Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'OLDNAME\mark', error code 0x534.
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15404)`. I might add that I am after a better understanding of the whole database owner thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default owner is going to be whoever creates the database. In your case, it sounds like you're using a local computer account as a windows login for SQL Server. So, the login name is in the form of `OLDNAME\user`; however, you would like new databases to be created with `NEWNAME\user` as the owner.

Changes to Windows accounts are not propagated  to SQL Server, so the old login name will persist until you manually change it. However, the login continues work because the SID is how SQL Server makes reference to it when authenticating the account.

To fix this issue you'll need to use the [ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command to change the login name from `OLDNAME\user` to `NEWNAME\user`.

```
ALTER LOGIN [OLDNAME\user] WITH NAME = [NEWNAME\user]
```

If you need to change the owner of an existing database, you can use `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`. I would recommend changing the database owner to someone other than a real user, such as [sa].

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<database_name>
    TO <domain>\<user>
```

Another option would be to use `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'owner_to_be'`, just ahead of the statement to be executed to create the database.

Comment: That would suggest that my current login must be wrong. I am using Windows authentication. Would the fix involve changing my login?

Comment: Changing the user after the event does fix the problem, but I wanted to see whether I could create new databases with the correct owner.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for. `SELECT name,type_desc FROM sys.server_principals;` gives me a list of logins, including the problematic login, and `ALTER LOGIN` fixes it. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that worked for you!

Comment: Classic `sp_changedbowner`, just used that one myself today. 

Comment: `sp_changedbowner` is to be [discontinued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I would recommend using `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<database_name> TO <domain>\<user>` instead.

Comment: Good call, @JohnK.N. I'll update my answer to reflect that. Old habits die hard.